# Mostrar un solo mensaje al insertar en BD windows forms y c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Estoy haciendo un sistema con windws forms y c#, Como puedo hacer para mostrar un solo mensaje de exito al insertar a través de un gridview a una BD, ya que por cada fila del gridview que se inserta en la BD me muestra el mensaje, o como hacer para mandar de una sola vez todo el gridview a la BD?

```html
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conexionString))
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    A= dataGridView1[0, row.Index].Value.ToString();
                    B= A.Substring(0, 3);
                    C= dataGridView1[1, row.Index].Value.ToString();
                    D= dataGridView1[2, row.Index].Value.ToString();
                    E= Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[3, row.Index].Value.ToString());
                    F= Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[4, row.Index].Value.ToString());
                    G= Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[5, row.Index].Value.ToString());
                    H= dataGridView1[6, row.Index].Value.ToString();
                    I= (dataGridView1[7, row.Index].Value.ToString());
                    J= (dataGridView1[8, row.Index].Value.ToString());
                    K= dataGridView1[9, row.Index].Value.ToString();
                    V= dataGridView1[10, row.Index].Value.ToString();
                    L= dataGridView1[11, row.Index].Value.ToString();
                    M= Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1[12, row.Index].Value.ToString());
                    N= dataGridView1[13, row.Index].Value.ToString();
                    W= Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1[14, row.Index].Value.ToString());
                    O= Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1[15, row.Index].Value.ToString());
                    P= dataGridView1[16, row.Index].Value.ToString();
                    Q= Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[17, row.Index].Value.ToString());
                    R= dataGridView1[18, row.Index].Value.ToString();
                    S= dataGridView1[19, row.Index].Value.ToString();
                    int.TryParse(dataGridView1[20, row.Index].Value.ToString(), out valor_default);
                    T= valor_default;
                    U= dataGridView1[21, row.Index].Value.ToString();
                    
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert_A", conn);

                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@numero", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = A
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@con", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = B
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@tipo_t", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = C
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@categoria", SqlDbType.Int).Value = D
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@categoria_c", SqlDbType.Int).Value = E
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@categoria_d", SqlDbType.Int).Value = F
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@status ", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = G
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@entrada ", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = H
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@salida", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = I
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@sentido", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = J
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@hora", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(K);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@fecha", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(V);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@importe_p", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = decimal.Parse(L);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@numero_r", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = M
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@importe_r", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = decimal.Parse(N);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@dif", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = decimal.Parse(O);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@tipo_dis", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = P
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@cas", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(Q);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@nombre_cas", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = R
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@op", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = S
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@numero_c", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(T);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@folio", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = U;
                    try
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Se ha registrado exitosamente");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Error");
                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception es)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(es.Message);

                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        conn.Close();
                    }

                }
            };

            //Procesar

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas ejecutando un `INSERT` siempre el `ExecuteNonQuery` va a ser mayor a cero, con poner el mensaje fuera del for alcanza, si hay un error saltara al catch

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conexionString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    //codigo

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert_A", conn);

                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    //parametros

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Se ha registrado exitosamente");

        }
        catch (Exception es)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(es.Message);
        }

    }
```

- mueve el tr..catch de forma global no en cada loop
- el open de la conexion solo se realiza una unica vez

Answer (score 2):

Saca tu mensaje fuera del foreach. Incluso puedes implementar una bandera para saber cual fue el resultado final.

```
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool bander = false;
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conexionString))
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    A= dataGridView1[0, row.Index].Value.ToString();
                    B= A.Substring(0, 3);
                    C= dataGridView1[1, row.Index].Value.ToString();
                    D= dataGridView1[2, row.Index].Value.ToString();
                    E= Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[3, row.Index].Value.ToString());
                    F= Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[4, row.Index].Value.ToString());
                    G= Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[5, row.Index].Value.ToString());
                    H= dataGridView1[6, row.Index].Value.ToString();
                    I= (dataGridView1[7, row.Index].Value.ToString());
                    J= (dataGridView1[8, row.Index].Value.ToString());
                    K= dataGridView1[9, row.Index].Value.ToString();
                    V= dataGridView1[10, row.Index].Value.ToString();
                    L= dataGridView1[11, row.Index].Value.ToString();
                    M= Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1[12, row.Index].Value.ToString());
                    N= dataGridView1[13, row.Index].Value.ToString();
                    W= Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1[14, row.Index].Value.ToString());
                    O= Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1[15, row.Index].Value.ToString());
                    P= dataGridView1[16, row.Index].Value.ToString();
                    Q= Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[17, row.Index].Value.ToString());
                    R= dataGridView1[18, row.Index].Value.ToString();
                    S= dataGridView1[19, row.Index].Value.ToString();
                    int.TryParse(dataGridView1[20, row.Index].Value.ToString(), out valor_default);
                    T= valor_default;
                    U= dataGridView1[21, row.Index].Value.ToString();

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert_A", conn);

                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@numero", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = A
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@con", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = B
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@tipo_t", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = C
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@categoria", SqlDbType.Int).Value = D
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@categoria_c", SqlDbType.Int).Value = E
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@categoria_d", SqlDbType.Int).Value = F
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@status ", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = G
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@entrada ", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = H
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@salida", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = I
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@sentido", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = J
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@hora", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(K);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@fecha", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(V);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@importe_p", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = decimal.Parse(L);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@numero_r", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = M
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@importe_r", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = decimal.Parse(N);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@dif", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = decimal.Parse(O);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@tipo_dis", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = P
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@cas", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(Q);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@nombre_cas", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = R
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@op", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = S
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@numero_c", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(T);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@folio", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = U;
                    try
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
                        {
                            bandera = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            bandera = false;
                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception es)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(es.Message);

                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                }
                if (bandera )
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Se ha registrado exitosamente");
                }   
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error");
                }

            };

            //Procesar

        }
```